# "SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function" Error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to upload this code to NetSuite

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/dialog'],

function(dialog){

   /**
     * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is committed.
     *
     * @param {Object} context
     * @param {Record} context.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} context.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */





   function validadeRate(context){

    try{

        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord
        var sublistName = context.sublistId

        if(sublistname ==='expense'){

            var categ = CurrentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: sublistName,
                fieldId: 'category'

            })
            if ((categ = 259) && (rate != 0.819)){
                var currIndex = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistIndex({
                    sublistId: sublistName
                })
             currIndex +=1

             var options = {
                title : 'Rate Incorreto!',
                message:'Por favor, verifique o valor informado no campo Rate na linha ' + currIndex + '.',                            
                }
                dialog.alert(options).then(function (result) { }).catch(function(result){})
                    
                return false
             }
            }
            return true
    }
    catch(ex){
        log.error('validateLine: ', ex.message)
    }

   }


    return {

        validadeRate : validadeRate

    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error when I'm trying to upload to file to Netsuite:

> Notice

> SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function.*

This is part of a function that will validade the rate for one expense category.

How can I solve this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NetSuite's 'Entry Point Script Validation' saying that the script is invalid because it doesn't include one of the predefined entry point (event) functions.  These functions are:

> fieldChanged
>
> lineInit
>
> pageInit
>
> postSourcing
>
> saveRecord
>
> sublistChanged
>
> validateDelete
>
> validateField
>
> validateInsert
>
> validateLine

You can work around this validation and upload the script by adding one of those entry points, even if it does nothing. For example, inside your `function (dialog)` function you can add a pageInit() function:

```
function pageInit(scriptContext) {}
```

and change your return block to:

```
return {

    validadeRate : validadeRate,
    pageInit: pageInit

}
```

Now it has a valid entry point and the validation should pass.

However, there may be an even easier way.  It appears (going by the JSDoc block), that your `validadeRate` function is supposed to be triggered each time a sublist line is added.  This is exactly what the `validateLine` entry point is for.  So you could just change the key in your return block to "validateLine"

```
return {
    validateLine: validadeRate
}
```

and NetSuite would know to call `validadeRate` each time a line is added.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified this as a Client Script module, but have not assigned a handler to any of the Client Script entry points. Read the Help document `SuiteScript 2.0 Client Script Entry Points and API`, and implement any one of the entry points in your module.

Comment: What is the deal with NS developers saying "Read the help document x" without providing a link

Answer (score 0):

Change return function as below. and test once.

---

return
{
validateLine : validadeRate
}